# Did kickbeat combos change?

Tags: kickbeat

If I recall correctly, in KickBeat when you successfully hit each enemy in sequence a combo counter will increment irrespective of bonuses. That is, you could single-hit each enemy and continue a combo, and missing bonuses wouldn't drop the combo.

While I was playing KickBeat today, missing *any* bonus was enough to reset the combo counter and multiplier.

Did this change recently in an update? I haven't heard anything about gameplay changes or seen any news about updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing powerups on Expert or Master level will break your combo.  On all other difficulty levels, it won't.